# cronjob not running on raspberry zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a cronjob defined on a raspberry zero. I've searched left and right, it seems to run, but does nothing.

This is the cronjob entry (taken from crontab -l so I'm sure it's there).

```
* * * * * python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1
```

I've set it to run every minute to debug. Also, I'm piping the output to a .txt file to catch any output from cron, but the .txt file remains empty.

The speedtest.py script has a line that generates output:

```
print('Start speedtest = speedtest-cli --simple')
```

When I run this manually, it writes to the .txt file. When cron does, noting happens.

speedtest.py is a python script that runs speedtest-cli to check ping, download and upload times.

The script runs without problems when I run it manually (I copied the command from the crontab entry), and writes the results to speedtest.csv in the same directory. Yet, something goes wrong when cron tries to run this script.

The cronjob seems to be running, I can see it with the tail command:

```
pi@iMon:~/iMon $ tail /var/log/syslog
Dec  6 13:48:01 iMon CRON[6562]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py >    
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:49:01 iMon CRON[6704]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:50:01 iMon CRON[6852]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:51:01 iMon CRON[6989]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:52:02 iMon CRON[7126]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:53:01 iMon CRON[7263]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:54:01 iMon CRON[7400]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:55:01 iMon CRON[7536]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 13:56:01 iMon CRON[7672]: (pi) CMD (python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > 
/home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
```

Any ideas what I'm missing or overlooking?

**UPDATE AFTER 1st COMMENTS:**

I executed the following command to find the path to python3:

```
which python3
```

The tail command shows that the cronjob is instantiated every minute, yet the script doesn't actually run as no files get updated.

```
pi@iMon:~/iMon $ tail /var/log/syslog
Dec  6 18:31:54 iMon systemd[1]: Started Session c12 of user pi.
Dec  6 18:32:01 iMon cron[252]: (pi) RELOAD (crontabs/pi)
Dec  6 18:32:01 iMon CRON[4246]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 18:32:43 iMon crontab[4384]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Dec  6 18:32:49 iMon crontab[4384]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Dec  6 18:33:01 iMon CRON[4402]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 18:33:11 iMon systemd[1]: session-c12.scope: Succeeded.
Dec  6 18:34:01 iMon CRON[4545]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 18:35:01 iMon CRON[4685]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
Dec  6 18:36:01 iMon CRON[4844]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py > /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you do edit the crontab to say "/usr/bin/python3" or whatever the location of your python is?

Comment: To find the location of your python3, do `which python3`.

Comment: Hi, I ran the which command, and prepended the path to python3 in the cronjob. Yet nothing happens. Would you perhaps have any ideas? Tks!

Comment: Add a line `SHELL=/bin/bash` and a line `PATH=/usr/bin/:/bin` to the top of your crontab. Then try this in the crontab: `python3 /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py >| /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.txt 2>&1` (note the 'force overwrite' change).

Comment: Regretfully it doesn't work yet. Never had such trouble with a cronjob...:-(

Comment: Solved, posted below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tips from Roadowl I could find the issues:

1. The .py script needs to write to /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.csv (with full path), not to speedtest.csv (without the path)
2. The cron command should be (debug - every minute):

   - - - - - /usr/bin/python3  /home/pi/iMon/speedtest.py

This last one should not be needed according to the docs, but won't work otherwise

Comment: If you had added a line with the PATH to the crontab file, like I advised, you would not need to specify the full path to python3.

Comment: Also, that crontab line won't work at all, since it uses bullets instead of asterisks.

Comment: the bullets come from some tye of formatting on Stackoverflow, they are asteriks in real life :-)